# Menu key is triggered twice android

Tags: android

If I the press menu key, it is triggered twice in all of my app's Activities 
I tried to override onKeyUp and onKeyDown but no use any suggestions as to why is this happening?? Thanks in advance code goes on like this..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private MainActivityDrawer mainActivityDrawer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mainActivityDrawer = (MainActivityDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main_activity_drawer_in);
        mainActivityDrawer.setUp(R.id.fragment_main_activity_drawer_in, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainDrawer1), toolbar);
        new clicklisteners().execute();
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = ((DrawerLayout) (findViewById(R.id.mainDrawer1)));
        drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(R.color.PrimaryColorDark);
        registerReceiver(err, new IntentFilter("ERROR_LOG_BUTTON_CLICKED"));
        //toolbar.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
            {
                ShowToast("Hello");
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            if(mainActivityDrawer.isOpened())
            {
                mainActivityDrawer.close();
            }
            else
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    ......
}
```

Comment: please show us some code. asking vague question is never helpful.

Comment: i posted the code of my MainActivity

Comment: what is this: `new clicklisteners().execute();`

Comment: That is an asynctask to create buttons and check box and assign onClicklistener and OnCheckedChchange listener

Comment: It seems the library 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' has a problem with the menu button ,When i made that v7:22.0.0 to v7:21.0.0 the menu key works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the library 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' has a problem with the menu button ,When i made that v7:22.0.0 to v7:21.0.0 the menu key works properly

Comment: 22.1.1 still has the issue